Why does this XSLT/XPath Concat returns a 'Nodetest expected here' error using MSXMLDom?
My XML (snip):
    <way id="1237072661">
      <nd ref="11488882051"/>
      <nd ref="11488882048"/>
      <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
    </way>

This XSLT/XPath returns a 'Nodetest expected here' error for the concat command when run using transformNode in MSXML6.
<xsl:copy-of select="*[tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']]/concat('&#xa;',name(),'/',@id)"/>

Without the concat it returns valid data.
It works as expected if parsed using Saxon HE (XPath2?).

XPath 1.0 does not allow the use of functions in location paths (other than in predicates).
Try something like:
<xsl:for-each select="*[tag[@k='railway'][@v='station']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xa;',name(),'/',@id)" />
</xsl:for-each>

instead.
